# functional calculus for n-tuples of commuting operators

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis

Good afternoon,

I'm reading some papers by Agler-Young in which the functional calculus for **n-tuples** of commuting operators (of Hilbert spaces) is utilized. So does anyone know a good introductory reference to read these things?

Thanks in advance,

Duc Anh

Comment: one of my professors recommands the book of John Wermer : Several Complex Variables and Banach Algebras.